# Virtualbox - cannot install bluetooth driver in Windows Guest

Tags: drivers, virtualbox, bluetooth, intel

I am trying to get my laptop's internal Bluetooth to work on a Windows 10 guest. lsusb shows:

`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub`

`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 062a:4101 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. Wireless Keyboard/Mouse`

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b59e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Chicony USB2.0 Camera`

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.`

`Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

I assume the Intel device is the Bluetooth one.

I believe I have followed all the steps in [Cant access in-built Bluetooth for Windows in Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963424/cant-access-in-built-bluetooth-for-windows-in-virtual-box). The Intel Bluetooth shows up as "Unknown Device". Windows 10 detects it, installs some software and pronounces it ready to use. However, when I look at "Unknown Device" it complains there is no driver. I have tried installing an Intel Wireless Bluetooth driver but the installation fails "*This software cannot be installed on your system*".

I don't know whether I am trying to install the wrong driver or whether there is something amiss with my VB configuration. Any clues?